# Tweaking this regular expression in Java

Tags: java, regex

```
"^(?:(2\d\d\d)\s+)?(?:Comm\. Rep\.\s+)?(?:CONG\s+)?(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(?:No\.\s+)?(\S+)(?:\s+\(.*?\))?$"
```

Currently this is able to parse a string like

```
2009 IA H.B. 184 (NS)
```

How can I make it parse a text like

```
2009 IA HEART RATE 184 (NS)
```

I'm looking for a tweak that'll make it parse the spaced word HEART RATE.

EDIT:
It seems to work as long as the third word is not spaced out. Like for e.g. 
It works for 2009 IA REG 184 (NS)  ...  But as soon as the third word is actually made of spaces it goes out of whack like HEART RATE for example.

Comment: A better description of the variables of your input would be nice - or, failing that, at least some more examples with the expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to make the assumption that you want all those space separated words, which doesn't work right now because you are trying to read the "third word" (the second regex capture group) `HEART RATE` by just reading until you find a space (the second `(\S+)`).

To fix this, I'll assume you the "third word" is **all the space separated words until you hit a number or a word starting with `No.`** (tell me if this assumption is wrong!). This is the `((?:\S|\s(?!\d|No\.))+)` in the solution.

Here is my solution:

```
"^(?:2\d{3}\s+)?(?:Comm\. Rep\.\s+)?(?:CONG\s+)?(\S+)\s+((?:\S|\s(?!\d|No\.))+)\s+(?:No\.\s+)?(\S+)(?:\s+\(.*?\))?$"
```

When I test it on

> 2009 IA H.B. 184 (NS)

it (still) finds the third word to be `H.B.`

When I test it on

> 2009 IA HEART RATE 184 (NS)

it finds the third word to be `HEART RATE`

When I test it on

> 2009 IA HEART RATE None 184 (NS)

it finds the third word to be `HEART RATE None`

When I test it on

> 2009 IA HEART RATE No. 184 (NS)

it finds the third word to be `HEART RATE`

Looks good?

PS [gskinner](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/) is awesome.

Comment: Carl Walsh, thanks for mentioning http://gskinner.com/RegExr/! Looks like a powerful tool.

Answer (score 0):

Let's break down the expression into its parts:

1. `^`
   Start at the beginning of a line.
2. `(?:(2\d\d\d)\s+)?`
   If a year appears, capture it in group 1 (group 0 is the whole thing). Doesn't matter if no year is given.
3. `(?:Comm\. Rep\.\s+)?`
   Accept the string "Comm. Rep." and one or more whitespace characters but don't capture it. Doesn't matter if it's not there.
4. `(?:CONG\s+)?`
   Accept the string "CONG" and one or more whitespace characters but don't capture it. Doesn't matter if it's not there.
5. `(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+`
   Two blocks of non-whitespace characters of at least one character length each followed by at least one whitespace must be there. Capture the the blocks in group 2 and 3.
6. `(?:No\.\s+)?`
   Accept the string "No." and one or more whitespace characters but don't capture it. Doesn't matter if it's not there.
7. `(\S+)`
   Another block of at least one non-whitespace character must be there. Capture it in group 4.
8. `(?:\s+\(.*?\))?`
   Accept at least one whitespace followed by anything as long as it's within brackets but don't capture it. Doesn't matter if it's not there.
9. `$`
   Then the line must end.

Here is how the parts map to the current match (omitting begin and end of line):

```
2009 IA H.B. 184 (NS)
---- ------- --- ----
2    5       7   8
```

Your problem lies within part 5 of the expression, because only two "blocks" are accepted:

```
2009 IA HEART RATE 184 (NS)
---- ------------- --- ----
2    ???           7   8
```

Assuming the string "HEART RATE" should also go into the third group you'll need to replace the 5th part with this:

`(\S+)\s+`
Accept a block of at least one non-whitespace character followed by at least one whitespace and capture it in group 2 (unchanged).

and

`(.+?)\s+`
Accept at least one character of anything followed by a whitespace and capture all but the last whitespace in group 3.

So, here is your needed expression as a whole:

```
^(?:(2\d\d\d)\s+)?(?:Comm\. Rep\.\s+)?(?:CONG\s+)?(\S+)\s+(.+?)\s+(?:No\.\s+)?(\S+)(?:\s+\(.*?\))?$
```

BTW, I am very happy with http://regexpal.com.

PS: The solution of Carl Walsh is a bit smarter performance-wise as it doesn't depend on non-greedy (or lazy) capturing.

Comment: Nice breakdown of the current regex. I know there weren't any test cases listed, but did you compare your regex against the initial one? It _matches_ the string `2009 IA H.B. 184 (NS)`... but it groups differently than the original regex. Group 3 used to get `184`, but now it is getting `(NS)` --probably not the right behavior. Group 2 is getting the `184` now...

Comment: You're right, the groups shifted. Good catch and props for keeping an eye on the semantics. I edited my solution to prevent the group mix-up. On that occasion I gave RegExr a try: very nice but, alas, depends on Flash :) Let's see if the OP add some hints on the requirements.